# Implement Multi-Reader / Multi-Writer Queue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue

I have application that Take `Pcap file` and send all the packet through the machine network card.
Because the DLLs that i am using (PcapDotNet) handle only `Pcap files` when the user choose `Wireshark file` i am opening `Wireshark` process (`Capinfos` in this case) using `Command line` and receive the file format before adding this file into my `ListView` so in case i have many file this take some time depends on the file size.
So after the user choose `Wireshark` files to add i do all the work in this function:

```
private IEnumerable<string> _source;

    public void Search()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(_source,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 //limit number of parallel threads here 
                },
            file =>
            {
                   // Here i am open Capinfos process and checking every file before add to my ListView
            });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }

        }).ContinueWith
            (t =>
            {
                 // Finish to check/add all files
            }
    , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
    );
    }
```

As you can see in this operation i am calling to `Search()`with collection of all the files that the user choose and open 2 `Capinfos` process simultaneously.
Now i have new issue that prevent me of using this function although my purpose is similar - add files to my application.
I have root folder on my network, this folder has many `sub-folders` (about 200 - 300) and in each folder i want to take `X` newest files (user define) so i am using this function:

```
public static List<string> List;

private static void ExcuteAqury(string directory)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(directory))
    {
        SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
        var files =
            Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.pcap", searchOption);
        List.AddRange(files);
    }
}
```

In this case the user choosing via `GridView` `Check Box` the wanted folders and this function called through loop again and again and each time adding the result to `List` and after finish this Work i am calling to `Search()` with my list (List).
My problem is that sometimes calling ExcuteAqury function many times take time so i wonder maybe to try different approach:
After every `ExcuteAqury function` Calling i want to take it's result and put it into `Queue` and immediately while my `Queue` is not empty start to Check those files and of course again i want to limit the concurrent `Threads` to 2 to avoid my machine to become slow.
So i wonder how to implemet this and will glad for some help / guidance

Comment: `List.AddRange(files);` kills all benefit from `EnumerateFiles()`.

Comment: Look for some examples of Producer/Consumer implementations. This isn't going anywhere.